# JScript within php

Tags: javascript, php

The below code included in php file and gets data from data base

```
$sqlUrl = "SELECT *
            FROM $category
            WHERE sub_category = '$subCategory'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sqlUrl);
```

now I need to display those data on the screen and thus I would like to load them on am html file in a specific division

```
<div id="div6">


</div>
```

I think that I can do it using JScript but I don't know how to do it

Comment: add this `<?php print_r($result); ?>` inside your `<div>`

Comment: @Tun Zarni Kyaw This works for testing reasons. But you cant format it properly, so its not the best idea if you want to show it to users.

Comment: Don't just inject variables into your SQL - if you don't escape them you're opening up for some SERIOUS SQL injection. Use prepared statements and bind variables.

Comment: yes, i agree @YUNOWORK, at least OP can get the idea. that's why i didn't write it as answer

Answer (score 1):

What the ... If you just want to print it, you dont need JavaScript:

```
<div id="div6">
    <?php foreach($result as $r) {
      echo $r;  
    } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually is a phpBB board and I have tried to write php code inside the html file but it doesn't permit me. That's the reason I am trying to write JScript.

Comment: You know that the file still has to be named as `file.php` in order to actually write PHP into it right?

Comment: Yes I know, I have already tried it but it creates trouble to other files on the phpBB board...

Comment: Bad phpBB board then. Every normal board is able to do that. Honestly, i have no idea how you want to create dynamic input depending on the output of your database if you cant combine .php and .html

Answer (score 0):

why you want to display results with JScript? You can do it like this also:

```
<div id="div6">
 <?php
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["Name"]."<br />";
  }
?>

</div>
```

for more details Plese refer: https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: did you forget `<?php ?>` tag or doesn't need `<?php ?>` tag?

Comment: Actually is a phpBB board and I have tried to write php code inside the html file but it doesn't permit me. That's the reason I am trying to write JScript.